# tring to change old message in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to create a scoreboard that refreshes itself.
I tried if I can edit the message, but I was unable to check it.

```
message(message_id)
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    message = discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message(message_id)
    await message.edit(contact = "hi")
```

this is the error I'm getting:

```
message = discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message(message_id)
TypeError: fetch_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not editing the message you're trying to edit an `int`. That int is likely the message ID if I may assume.

If so then you need to retrieve the message by that id then edit the message itself. This can be done using [`fetch_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message)

So your changed code would become:

```
message_id = 842098851431186442
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    message = Client.fetch_message(message_id)
    await message.edit(contact = "hi")
```

Comment: it doesn't work, :
TypeError: fetch_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Comment: Try using client to fetch message